# Using the same Power Automate approval flow in many SharePoint document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, approval-process, maintenance, azure-automation

I have a working workflow in Power Automate connected to one document library. The approvers are listed in a special SharePoint group for that document library.

This workflow is using my user connections to run, but the recommendation of my organization is to use a special service account to avoid problems when a person is leaving the organization.
So I will recreate the workflow using the new credentials/connections of the service account.

The workflow is now so popular that I have been asked to add it to 20 other document libraries. If I make twenty copies of the workflows I am seeing the risk that I will get a lot of maintenance work.
For instance, if I need to add functionality I am afraid I have to do the same work in twenty different workflows.

So, can I parameterize the names of the document libraries (and its approver group)? Or are there any tricks with the deployment of the workflows that can help me (for instance PnP PowerShell)?
What is best practice for using the same workflow for several document libraries?

Edit:
I am using:

- `For a selected file`
- `Get file properties`
- `Get file metadata`
- `Start and wait for an approval`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't link/share a Flow between document libraries at this time.

Some workarounds for the time being would likely bea PowerApp that users could use to change the approval status across all document libraries, or create secondary Flows for each document Library and nest the Flows with the main Flow.

For more information about nesting Flows, please view the **[How to build nested flows with the HTTP action](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/build-nested-flows/)** article.

Here is a similar case for your reference.

- **[Approval Flow on multiple SharePoint Libraries](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Approval-Flow-on-multiple-SharePoint-Libraries/td-p/295393)**